# Most options are disabled/greyed-out in GIMP

Tags: gimp, image-processing, image-editor

I'm attempting to resize an image and save the resizes image. Google taught me that I should be looking for the scale image option, however it's disabled along with Save Image, Export image and most options. I then attempted to look into this everything says I need to set the mode to RGB, but it's already on RBG. What's gone wrong?

Comment: Are you using 14.04?

Comment: Restart gimp and it usually works again. I had the same problem on Ubuntu 13.10 just now, so it's not about using 14.04.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Using gimp 2.8.6 with Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Restarting GIMP fixed the issue for me on 13.10. But it's kinda annoying to have to do it every time.

Comment: On 2013.10 restarting 4 times did not solve the problem, but when I tried launching without command-line arguments it finally worked (so no `gimp mypic.jpeg &`)

Comment: Happened to me today, after I had done many edits to an image (one specific layer). How I saved my work? I copied the layer to clipboard, then opened another instance of gimp with the -n (new instance) switch on CLI ```gimp -n```. There did New > from Clipboard, and saved it there.